# Destructuring but also returning the source object

Tags: javascript, destructuring

One can do

```
import Foo, { bar } from 'foo-with-bar'
```

However, **is something similar possible using destructuring**, like

```
let { * as Foo, bar } = getFooBar()
```

?

Let's assume `getFooBar()` and the `foo-with-bar` module return

```
{ foo: 1, bar: a => console.log(a) }
```

and after the `import`/`let`, this is expected to print `1`:

```
bar(Foo.foo)
```

Comment: Import declarations have nothing to do with destructuring.

Comment: Right... the question stands, regardless

Comment: @PeteV. I would do `var bar = fooWithBar.bar` and not mind there's an extra bar in foo

Comment: @JanDvorak the `import` is just an example, I have an object, not a module

Comment: Are you looking for property spreading, as in `let {bar, ...Foo} = getFooBar();`?

Comment: I mean, if you want an object with a property + an object without that property, why won't the original object with the property suffice?

Comment: @JanDvorak because I don't have a reference to it outright, updated the question to better reflect this. Really just looking for a syntax as elegant as `import`

Comment: @torazaburo I might be, worth adding this as an answer, I'm testing it but Node.js `6.5.0` doesn't seem to like this syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you're doing destructuring you already have split the object up in properties. However you can just use two assignments:

```
let Foo = getFooBar();
let { bar } = Foo;
```

or:

```
let Foo, { bar } = Foo = getFooBar(); // very questionable and unmaintainable
let Foo = getFooBar(), { var } = Foo; // better
```

There is also a [object rest property proposal](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) with an experimental transpiler plugin that lets you do

```
let { bar, ...Foo } = getFooBar();
```

but `Foo` will be a new object here and lack the `bar` property.

Comment: Thank you, I am ok with `let Foo, { bar } = Foo = getFooBar()`

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use a namespace import together with named imports (you can however use it together with a default import). You would have to use two separate import declarations:

```
import * as Foo from 'foo-with-bar';
import { bar } from 'foo-with-bar';
```

Comment: I think (but can't really tell) that this question is not about imports. He's looking for a non-existent variety of destructuring.

Comment: According to MDN I can?

Comment: @torazaburo: Yes, I really can't tell what the question is about. Downvoted and posted two answers :-)